# Add a note/comment to a GitHub pull request, before the request has been opened

Tags: github

I'm looking for a way to add a note to a pull request on GitHub but in advance of the branch being ready to have the pull request created/opened.

My use case here is that I want to add some notes for the reviewer that explain things to do with the merge/deploy process. They are not applicable to the code itself so putting them in a comment in the code doesn't make sense.

I realise that things like what I'm trying to do here could have their own tool built/used to handle them, but I'm not looking for that right now. The perfect solution in my mind would be something similar to one of the following:

- Opening a pull request on the branch but in a status of "Pending request" and then I can add the comments etc but it does not sit in the list of open pull requests.
- The ability to "Save draft" on the pull request screen so I can keep the notes box updated without actually creating the pull request.
- To be able to store a markdown file in a specific place (e.g. `.ghpr` in the root of the repo) which would automatically get its contents put into the notes box on pull request opening. The file would then be deleted on creation of the pull request so it doesn't actually exist in master once merged in.

The 3rd option would probably be my preferred method.

Currently I'm maintaining a file in the code base with my notes in it which just before opening the PR, I'll delete having copied the contents into the PR notes. I don't want to forget to do this last step and so a better solution could be found.

Comment: While not expressly off-topic here, being a tool so closely associated with programming, I think you'll have a much better chance of a good answer at [so].

Comment: Looked into this? https://github.com/blog/1184-contributing-guidelines